# docker-compose with postgres image not working

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to have a `nestjs` app with a `psql` database dockerized. I have a `docker-compose.yml`:

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3.8'
services:
  
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    container_name: postgres_albert
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

volumes:
  postgres:
    name: volume-uni
```

Then I access the container:

```
docker exec -it 36cf6358a019 bash
```

And try to use psql:

```
psql -U postgres
```

I get following error:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

I don't understand, `postgres` is the official user and is there when installation. I used the official image without docker-compose with the `postgres` user and it worked. I tried also changing users but no success

Answer (score 1):

I finally fix it by adding the `POSTGRES_DB` env var in the environment section of the docker-compose.yml. In the documentation is explained that if data folder is populated, it takes some values. Like the db name is the user etc.

https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres